# (∃a)(∀b)(∃c)(∀d)(a · c = d · b) as 2 equal formulas using only one type of quantifier

Tags: predicate-logic

How to do 2 equal formulas using only one type of quantifier

(∃a)(∀b)(∃c)(∀d)(a · c = d · b)

I have to use only ∀ in the first formula and only ∃ in the second formula.

Comment: Think about the deMorgan laws.

Comment: @MatthewDaly 1) ¬(∀a)¬(∀b)(∀c)(∀d)(a . c = d . b) and 2) (∃a)¬(∃b)¬(∃c)(∃d)(a . c = d . b) ?

Comment: You'd have to wrap negations around both quantifiers you're shifting.  But, yeah, I don't think it's anything more complicated than that.

Comment: 1) ¬(∀a)(∀b)¬(∀c)(∀d)(a . c = d . b) and 2) (∃a)¬(∃b)(∃c)¬(∃d)(a . c = d . b)